# event callback not firing in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, callback, webrtc, dom-events

I am creating a sample application for audio conferencing using WebRTC. What I am trying to do is creating a `RTCpeerconnection` object and passing it remote description received from the caller. Once remote description is set then then 'onaddstream' event is fired for the peer-connection object, where we can set the stream received in remote description to some audio/video control as shown in example code below:

```
function call() {        
    chatHub.server.connect('receiver');        
    pc2 = new RTCPeerConnection(null, pcConstraints);
    pc2.onicecandidate = iceCallback2;
    pc2.onaddstream = gotRemoteStream; 
}
function gotDescription1(desc) { 
    var dessc = new RTCSessionDescription({ type: 'offer', sdp: desc });    
    pc2.setRemoteDescription(dessc);
}
function gotRemoteStream(e) { 
    //attaching the stream to UI controls
    audio2 = attachMediaStream(audio2, e.stream);
    audio2.play();  
    pc2.createAnswer(gotDescription2, onCreateSessionDescriptionError,sdpConstraints);
    callButton.disabled = true;
    hangupButton.disabled = false;
}
function gotDescription2(desc) {
    pc2.setLocalDescription(desc);      
}
function iceCallback2(event) {
    //---foo----
}
```

as clear from sample code process starts from call method , which set up a `PeerConnection` object and set its events callback, then `gotDescription1` is called by some code element, now this is where we set remoteDescription which should fire `gotRemoteStream` internally.

All this is working fine in major browsers except Firefox, remote description is set for object but there is no callback for `gotStream`.

Check this for possible explanation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection#Initializing_the_call

Comment: You have asked 9 questions but not marked any as answered. Perhaps you should do so in order to get more help from SO users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [spec](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#widl-RTCPeerConnection-onaddstream) says about onaddstream:

> It is called any time a MediaStream is added by the remote peer. This will be fired only as a result of setRemoteDescription. Onnaddstream happens as early as possible after the setRemoteDescription. This callback does not wait for a given media stream to be accepted or rejected via SDP negotiation.

Firefox currently doesn't fire onaddstream until negotiation is complete; see [Bug 1122306](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1122306)

In any case, media shouldn't flow until you do SetLocalDescription(), so just make it not gate your acceptance.